# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1 on JTable creation/tablechanged

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jtable, abstracttablemodel

I have read through all the threads out there that looked as if they could solve my problem and I've also read all the answers on here, but I'm still at my wit's end. I'm not sure why the exception is thrown, although I have a feeling this might be to do with `threading`. If it does, please let me know where to include the `new Runnable()`and whether to `invokeLater()` or `invokeAndWait()`, as I have tried it to no avail.

Please bear with me while I give you the code that leads to the exception + the stacktrace (below).

**EDIT**: I had included a number of `syso`s in the `AnnoTable` section just before `tableChanged` is called and they don't show up in the console, hence I think the problem must occur even before the application gets to that point, i.e. either when it's called from `AAView` or when data and table model are instantiated...

**EDIT II**: The problem was the overwritten `tableChanged` method. That would obviously fire an Exception. I've removed the `tableChanged()` call (which wouldn't make a difference) as well. Now I've got another problem: understanding how a change in the underlying data (`AnnoData`) can automatically update the table. Although this is perhaps for another query (after an extended Google search), please feel free to post helpful comments in this thread, as I'll continue reading it... THANKS A LOT for all the helpful comments and tips!

**EDIT III:*** I've solved the problem. I needed to instantiate another object from `AnnoData`, pass that to a new instance of `AnnoTableModel`, set this instance to my table and THEN `fireTableDataChanged()`.

**EDIT IV:** Okay, so `fireTableDataChanged()` (as used in EDIT III) is unnecessary after all. I still would want to use it rather than creating new objects all the time. I guess I should ask a new question... Thanks!

This method in `AAView` should create an object extending a `JTable`, put it into a `JScrollPane`, etc. (the latter does work).

```
private JPanel createAnnoTablePanel() {
    annoTablePanel = new JPanel();
    annoTable = new AnnoTable(aameth);
    setAnnoTable(annoTable);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(getAnnoTable());
    annoTablePanel.add(scrollPane);
    return annoTablePanel;
}
```

Here is the class `AnnoTable` (`aameth` is an instance object containing business logic to access a data model, works fine).

```
public class AnnoTable extends JTable implements TableModelListener
{

  public AnnoTable(AAMethods aameth)
  {

     int tokenCount = aameth.getTokenCount();

     AnnoData annoData = new AnnoData(aameth); // cf. below, AnnoData is a Vector(Vector<Object>,String[])

     TableModel tableModel = new AnnoTableModel(annoData.getAnnoData(),
     // AnnoTableModel extends AbstractTableModel(Vector, String[])
     annoData.getColTitles());
     setModel(tableModel);
     getModel().addTableModelListener(this);
     TableModelEvent tme = new TableModelEvent(tableModel);
     this.tableChanged(tme);
     setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
     setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
     getColumnModel().getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new AnnoTableSelectionListener(this));
     setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(this.getPreferredSize());

  }

  public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
  int row = e.getFirstRow();
     int column = e.getColumn();
     AbstractTableModel model = (AbstractTableModel)e.getSource();
     String columnName = model.getColumnName(column);
     Object data = model.getValueAt(row, column); // This is where the exception is thrown!
  }
}
```

If you need the source code for `AnnoTableModel()` (which is a fairly generic extension of `AbstractTableModel`) or `AnnoData` (which constructs a `Vector` containing three `Vector<Object>` and a `String[]` for column titles), please let me know.

Here's the stacktrace.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.getValueAt(Unknown Source)
at package.AnnoTable.tableChanged(AnnoTable.java:52)
at javax.swing.JTable.setModel(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JTable.<init>(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JTable.<init>(Unknown Source)
at package.AnnoTable.<init>(AnnoTable.java:25)
at package.AAView.createAnnoTablePanel(AAView.java:464)
at package.AAView.createNorthPanel(AAView.java:455)
at package.AAView.displayAndAnnotate(AAView.java:444)
at package.AAView.loadProject(AAView.java:333)
at package.AAView.actionPerformed(AAView.java:286)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Actions.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.notifyAction(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBinding(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JMenuBar.processBindingForKeyStrokeRecursive(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JMenuBar.processBindingForKeyStrokeRecursive(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JMenuBar.processBindingForKeyStrokeRecursive(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JMenuBar.processKeyBinding(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.KeyboardManager.fireBinding(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.KeyboardManager.fireKeyboardAction(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindingsForAllComponents(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindings(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I can see the `EDT` in there so from what I've learned this might really be a problem of threading. However, I don't know how to find out where I should start a new `Thread` (or invoke a `new Runnable()`.

On a side note, the Exception only started appearing when I changed `AnnoTable` to extend `JTable` rather than `JPanel`. Originally I had `AnnoTable` not only construct the table but also wrap it in a scroll pane and add this to a new `JPanel`. But because I wanted to `fireTableDataChanged` from a Class that only knew of `AAView` (which also features a `setAnnoTable()` method) I wanted to do it the correct way, whereas before it worked just fine. Murphy's law?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A rowIndex of -1 (==TableModelEvent.HEADER_ROW) indicates that the model's structure has changed completely. Such an event is fired internally by the JTable on setModel. Read the api doc of TableModelEvent to fully understand which types/values to expect in the listener's tableChanged.

BTW, @AKJ is right - no need to fire any TableModelEvents in your table code. Make the *model* fire the events as appropriate

Comment: @kleopatra: Thank you. Of course in my case the `setModel()` would call my hardcoded `tableChanged()` (cf. EDIT II) which was expecting to receive parameters it didn't receive. I've deleted the method. The table now displays correctly, but whenever something is changed in `annoData` (via a method that also does `((AbstractTableModel)aaView.getAnnoTable().getModel()).fireTableDataChanged()` after everything is set in `annoData`), the table still doesn't update... Perhaps that should be asked in a new query though, UNLESS someone here has a quick answer :). Thanks to all!

Comment: _do not_ call any of the model's fireXX methods from any code external to the model. Instead implement the _model_ to do so when anything changed

Comment: @kleopatra: I've solved the problem (cf. EDIT III) by creating another instance of `AnnoData` (which compiles a `Vector` of `Vector`s and a `String[]` from an underlying XML model), created a new model instance (passing the new `AnnoData` object to it), set the new model to the table and `fireTableDataChanged()` on the model (just found out that the latter is unnecessary). **Is there a way to circumvent instantiating a new `AnnoData` object and going through the motions again? How would `fireTableDataChanged()` be used in this context?** But perhaps that's for a new query after all...

Answer (score 3):

This means that you are passing `-1` as row or column. This is not permitted - make sure you pass a correct value.

Answer (score 3):

I have a feeling that your problem is here:

```
TableModelEvent tme = new TableModelEvent(tableModel);      
this.tableChanged(tme); 
->
  int column = e.getColumn();     
  AbstractTableModel model = (AbstractTableModel)e.getSource();     
  String columnName = model.getColumnName(column);
```

Because you haven't specified a `row` or `column` value, the `getColumn()` and `getRow()` calls will return -1, which you are then passing to `getValueAt()`.

Try looking at the constructor for [TableModelEvent](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/event/TableModelEvent.html).  It has options for specifying those row/column values.

Comment: wrong - the upper two lines are unrelated to the exception (see the stacktrace :-) Apart from that, the analysis is correct: listener code must guard against 'special values' (HEADER_ROW, ALL_COLUMNS) in row/column index

Answer (score 3):

```
TableModelEvent tme = new TableModelEvent(tableModel);
this.tableChanged(tme);
```

I don't see any need of this call. As pointed by other posters this is the cause of your problem.

If you are implementing the table model correctly, whenever you update the table model the jtable will automatically get notifications and you don't need to write the tableChanged() method as well. So I am lost why you need to call tableChanged() explicitly.

Whenever you want to update the table just update the model. Also at first glance there does not seem to be any threading issue involved.

Answer (score 0):

Your AnnoTable constructor is leaking references to the incompletely constructed "this" object.  Also, registering Listeners from the constructor is not safe.  [enter link description here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp07265/index.html)

Build your objects doing the least amount of work possible in the constructor and then operate on the fully built objects.  Add listeners, adjust the models, fireEvents etc...